# Asp.net C# to MVC 4.0 Design calender issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dtAppoinment, new { @class = "form-control"},data-plugin-datepicker)

```
data-plugin-datepicker where to set?
```

Comment: are you using bootstrap datepicker or datetimepicker? And what kind of issue are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the Calendar isn't showing. If you are using bootstrap datepicker then edit your code to be like below

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.dtAppoinment, new { @class = "form-control datePicker"})
```